# Can't import a variable from a function in another script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I have 2 scripts : `enregistrement.py` and `main.py`
`enregistrement.py` has the following code : (both of the programs have all the library needed)

```py
import pickle
global argent_fiche, argent_poche, royaume_pari, argent_pari, exploit, role, nom, couleur, souterrain, aerien, paris_faits, pari_gagnes, moyenne_pari, inventaire, pari_recupere
def loadfiche(identifiant):
    fiche_open = open(f"fiche de {identifiant}","rb")
    print(identifiant)
    fiche_load = pickle.load(fiche_open)
    argent_fiche = fiche_load[1] 
    argent_poche = fiche_load[2] 
    royaume_pari = fiche_load[3] 
    argent_pari = fiche_load[4] 
    exploit = fiche_load[5] 
    role = fiche_load[6] 
    nom = fiche_load[7] 
    couleur = fiche_load[8] 
    souterrain = fiche_load[9] 
    aerien = fiche_load[10] 
    paris_faits = fiche_load[11] 
    pari_gagnes = fiche_load[12] 
    moyenne_pari = fiche_load[13] 
    inventaire = fiche_load[14]
    pari_recupere = fiche_load[15] 
    fiche_open.close()
    global fiche_joueur
    fiche_joueur = {1 : argent_fiche, 2 : argent_poche, 3 : royaume_pari, 4 : argent_pari, 5 : exploit, 6 : role, 7 : nom, 8 : couleur, 9 : souterrain, 10 : aerien, 11 : paris_faits,
            12 : pari_gagnes, 13 : moyenne_pari, 14 : inventaire, 15 : pari_recupere}
```

And `main.py` have the following code :

```py
from turtle import color
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import random
import datetime
import time
import pickle
from enregistrement import *
@bot.command()
async def fiche(ctx,*, membre : discord.Member='∅'):
    global user
    if membre != '∅':
        user = membre.id
        pfp = membre.avatar_url
    if membre == '∅' :
        user = ctx.author.id
        pfp = ctx.author.avatar_url          
    loadfiche(user)
    from enregistrement import fiche_joueur 
    embed = discord.Embed(title = None, description = None,color = 0x7289da)
    embed.set_author(name=nom, icon_url = pfp)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = "random URL")
    embed.add_field(name = (":credit_card: | Argent en banque"), value = argent_fiche ,inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = (":dollar: | Argent en poche"), value = argent_poche, inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = (":four_leaf_clover: | Nombre d'exploit"), value = exploit,inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = (":arrows_counterclockwise: | Pari en cours"), value = royaume_pari,inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = (":chart_with_upwards_trend: | Montant parié"), value = argent_pari,inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = (rang[role]), value = emote_rang[role],inline = False)
    embed.set_footer(text = ctx.author.id)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

And I get the error `"nom"` is not defined, can someone help?

Comment: seems like the dictionnary is not imported in main.py

Comment: What's the reasoning behind creating so many global variables? This all seems very messy. Couldn't you just make the function `loadfiche()` return `fiche_joueur` (which will contain all the variables) and then you